# Unable to resolve module `@expo/vector-icons/FontAwesome` from

Tags: react-native, expo

I just returned to my React Native project in which I am using Expo and I am getting the error message:

> Unable to resolve module `@expo/vector-icons/FontAwesome`
>   from.../node_modules/react-native-elements/src/social/SocialIcon.js`:
>   Module`@expo/vector-icons/FontAwesome` does not exist in the Haste
>   module map

I have followed the three suggestions that go along with the error to get it working again to no avail.

Anybody have any idea what is going on here?

Could it have something to do with the cloning process? So when I initialized this app I used `expo init <nameOfProject>`

When I cloned it on this machine I am currently on, I am using `npm install` after cloning it.

Could I have missed something here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, you can delete the `node_modules` folder and re-install it with `yarn`.

Comment: Poptocrack, do we have to use FontAwesome with Expo? I am relatively new to it and I am confused as to why I am dealing with FontAwesome at all, I have not loaded it up anywhere. I used this: `import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from "react-native";`. Is the error coming from importing that `Stylesheet`?

Comment: Well, it's part of the Expo's sdk, so you can't remove it. Normally, you just have to do expo init project-name. Try to take a look on their forums, I will delete my answer soon.

Comment: Could that be a gotcha then when it comes time to clone a project created with `expo init`?

Comment: I&#39;ve never encountered this issue. What is happening when you delete the node module folder, and then install it with yarn

Comment: `yarn install` did it. What is that all about? Please explain why this worked as an answer and I will check it off.

Comment: Hard to tell, in some cases, npm and yarn are working differently. I don't know why exactly. I ll edit the original answer.

Comment: Then you hit the 20 other libs not working with yarn.